# How to check if Remote API is enabled in your Confluence installation without admin rights

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

Is there a way to find out if the Remote API is enabled on our Confluence installation if I do not have admin rights to our confluence

I can see the WSDSL, but while testing with this [downloaded client](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/bob_swift/confluence-cli/downloads/confluence-cli-2.1.0-distribution.zip) I keep timing out on login. I can not contact my administrators without going through god knows how many channels so I'm hoping there's another way to know if the Remote API is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

To check if the confluence API is enabled without admin access:

Try accessing *http://<your-confluence-server>/rpc/xmlrpc*

If the API is **enabled**, you will simply get a blank page.

If the API is **disabled**, you will get an error "HTTP Status 403 - Remote API is not enabled on this server. Ask a site administrator to enable it."

This is at least applicable in my Confluence 3.2 environment.