# How to upload a file to Atlassian Confluence page using curl

Tags: python, curl, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to upload an .xls file to a Confluence wiki page following the guidelines given in the Remote API documentation : 
https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-server-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples#ConfluenceRESTAPIExamples-Uploadanattachment

```
curl -v -S -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@myfile.txt" -F "comment=this is my file" "http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/3604482/child/attachment" | python -mjson.tool
```

This is what I am doing:

```
curl -v -S -u username:password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@/path/to/local/excelsheet.xls" https://<Confluence server>/display/page
```

I omitted the Python -mjson.tool as it says 'No JSON object could be decoded' and it didn't make sense as I am not posting JSON.

However the above curl command is not working for me. I see the html of the target page on my console and the file doesn't get uploaded. I tried modifying the curl command in several ways but nothing worked.

Also for the URL of the page I am trying to upload to, it doesn't have any contentID as suggested in the documentation. The target URL is a page which accepts attachments and shows the uploaded file list.

Could someone please point out where am I going wrong? I don't have much experience with Curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use REST API in url: `.../confluence/rest/api/content/$PAGE_ID/child/attachment` and now you are using url of view page.

Comment: I tried this as well. It didn't work :( I looked up the page_id from the Page Information section under Tools.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Also, make sure that: 1) rest api is enabled by admin (by default it's off IIRC), 2) you have rights to use it, 3) it is not restricted to intranet/whitelist/otherwise_authorized_users, 4) it is under the same host as 'viewable' confluence.

Comment: I tried curl -v -S -u username:password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@test.txt" -F "comment=this is my file" "https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/889912330/child/attachment"  889912330 is the page id that I found when I looked it up under Tools. On the console, it returns a 404 along with all the html.

Comment: you should wrap your comment with single quotes: `curl -v -S -u username:password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@test.txt" -F "comment='this is my file'" "http://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/889912330/child`

Comment: I removed the comments altogether. curl -v -S -u username:password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@test.txt" "https://<confluence server>/confluence/rest/api/content/889912330/child/attachment. Still not working :(

Comment: Are you completely sure that you have rest api enabled on your confluence and have rights to use it?

Comment: I used the test given in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853316/how-to-check-if-remote-api-is-enabled-in-your-confluence-installation-without-ad  ..I could see the blank page. I am also shooting an email to the admin to make it very sure that Remote API is enabled and I can access it.

Comment: I'll update it here what I hear from the admin. Thanks for  your help!

Comment: The admin responded. Turns out that Confluence Remote API is blocked on our network! But nevertheless, thanks a lot for helping me with this.

Answer (score 4):

[David Vonka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372612/david-vonka) answer is correct except for header "**X-Atlassian-Token**" value.  It must be "**no-check**" (instead of "**nocheck**")

So corrected command is:

```
curl -v -S -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file_0=@<file name>" -F "comment_0=<upload comment>" "http://<server>:<port>/<context>/pages/doattachfile.action?pageId=<page id>&os_username=<username>&os_password=<password>"
```

**NOTE**: *replace all the <...> placeholders with your values*

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that confluence rest api allows file upload. Please do this instead

```
curl -v -S -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file_0=@<file name>" -F "comment_0=<upload comment>" "http://<server>:<port>/<context>/pages/doattachfile.action?pageId=<page id>&os_username=<username>&os_password=<password>"
```

replace all the <...> placeholders with your values

Comment: works for me on Confluence 3.5, the newer version do indeed have a res api that allows upload.

Answer (score 0):

The API POST syntax should be corrected from "https://ConfluenceServer/display/page" to the correct res/api/content syntax eg: "https://companyName.atlassian.net/display/rest/api/content/pageIDxxxxx":

```
 curl -v -S  -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file_0=@<file name>" -F "comment_0=<upload comment>" https://<companyName>.atlassian.net/display/rest/api/content/<pageID15398762>/child/attachment
```

The pageID can be found in the URL display page. For example: 
https://companyName.atlassian.net/display/spaces/DEV/pages/pageID15398762/Page+Title+Name

For more API syntax details please refer to this documentation:
https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/REST/6.6.0/#content-createContent