# Integrate file content to confluence from Jenkins

Tags: layout, jenkins, wiki, confluence

(sorry for my english)

I have a job Jenkins that executes a script that will check free space on different tablespaces of a Oracle Database,then put in a file with a good layout.

Finally, jenkins job will publish the file contained in the wiki Confluence .

My problem is that the layout does not stay ... I tested several solutions but nothing happens

please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this quite easily with the [Confluence REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api)

Have your jenkins job create the file (or generate the content).
Then in an "execute shell" simply call the confluence REST API with curl, and either create a page with the content, or upload the file as an attachment.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551708/how-to-upload-a-file-to-atlassian-confluence-page-using-curl) This question will help you too.